# UINavigation bar jumps when presenting modal view controller

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller

When I present modal view controller I have a quick jump **from**:

[image]

**to**:

[image]

I could implement the method inside this controller:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

but this affect on view after my modal (this is visible and it is not good):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

When you dismiss modal view controller, at that time again show status bar. See following snippet.

```
@IBAction func okaButtonClicked (sender:UIButton) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false;
    })
}
```